# Docvarsfrom = filenames error message in Quanteda in R: "Filename elements are not equal in length"

Tags: r, corpus, quanteda

I am putting together a corpus in quanteda in R and seem to be stuck at the first step. I want to specify that docvars should be taken from the filenames of my corpus. I had already named all files in the same convention, separated with underscores. However I am consistently receiving the error message "Filename elements are not equal in length"

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq8e3.png)

This is the code I have used that resulted in the error

[Code at present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEcSb.png)

The naming convention is a variation on "UK_manif_1992_Con_Major_FourthTerm_Win_Gov" for every file. Some have 7 variables and others 8 (different document types, indicated by the second variable) but I tried only creating the corpus using one kind of document type with readtext, and the subsequent step using docvarsfrom resulted in the same error.

I'd appreciate any advice you can offer.

Comment: The problem is that this method only works if the "_"-separated filename elements are equal in number. So if some filenames have 7 elements and others have 8, then this will not work. Anyway, your code calling `readtext()` indicates nine elements, matching none of your filenames.

Comment: Thanks very much @KenBenoit! That makes sense & the fix is simple. I have 7/8/9 variables because of interest in minor differences between document types. Is the best way to go about that instead to simplify/reduce the variables for the combined corpus, and only have additional variables if I want to analyse the different document types separately? Also, the 9th variable was a variation on the “unique” you used during the ANU course earlier this year. There are a few documents in my dataset that have e.g. two occurrences in a year. How should I work this into the filenames and/or the code?

Comment: Thanks very much @KenBenoit. You can scrap my previous comment. I bumped up the variable count to 13 to encompass all of this information. Some of those will only hold interesting data for one or two of the document types and otherwise be superfluous. It has now read in to R fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (Of course I'm open to and feedback on that approach but that's stepping into methodological decision making rather than help with code!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.